# Cheating your Boss is not easy

Tags: wordplay, reverse-puzzling

I stole the [thought reading device](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42813/cheating-is-efficient-but-only-until-you-get-caught) from [Ankoganit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25412/ankoganit). I have already understood how to fit it into people. And now, I have fitted it in the neck of my Boss. Now, I get to know what is going in his silly little head all the time. Now, I can know why he is so cranky every time and if possible, I might know all his likes and earn myself a raise.

I got to my office early today, and I have my headphones. Now, all I have to wait is for him to reach the office.

My wait is not long. He is here! And just like always, he is into his office straightaway without even batting an eye to the rest of us. Arrogant fellow!

I now switch on my device and listen to his thoughts. It is a bit fast, but I am able to understand some stuff in there.

> “Ok, time to see. Ok, the first one. Hmm, Only 5? Og... No. . Wrong order. Oh, easy, easy. The game. What do we have? Bee and.
>   5 again. Err... Bob...No. This is Slightly tough. Oh, Yes! So, the other, I get a tea.
>   Now, 6. What’s this? Vag..No,no,no. Ah, Yes! Pebbles. Oh, Ev Ji. Nice to meet you.

At this time, a client came to meet him and it is probably a deal with a big company. I can't reveal the details about that meeting here due to technical reasons. (Yes, I heard everything.). After the client went away,

> Where was I? Last one. 6 again. This is easy. sla.. Oh¸ No. It doesn’t fit. Now what? If only this thing had clues... What can it be? Oh, Yes! Principles. Ok, Short that is.
>   Done it all. Now, the picture. What’s this? “Survive, won’t? Something blood..” 1 and 8.

At this point, the streaming became noisy and unclear. And, I couldn't hear anything. I want to compliment my Boss on his good solving skills (if he ever has one) and be on his good books.

**Can you help me find out what was the last question? And What exactly was the final answer?**

HINT 1:

> I heard some letters could sound like words.

HINT 2:

> The extra letters that I wrote at the end of each word is important. It also helps to find out which word it was.

Comment: Is there any reason there is the diacritical mark U+008B ¸ in 'Oh¸ No. It doesn’t fit. Now what?' (second block quote)?

Comment: @boboquack any sort of punctuation error/odd punctuation mark is not intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be a

> [Jumble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumble). There are several anagrams, unclued, and certain letters from those are taken to form a final anagram, clued by a picture (normally a pun).

The first clue is

> Bingo - as noted by @Technidot. The letters taken are B and N (maybe "and" sounds like N?).

The second clue is

> Abbot. We have the letters of bob and A T ("a tea"), which are taken.

The third clue is

> Gravel? Not sure about this one, as I'm not sure how " Oh Ev Ji" (O, F, G?) comes into it, but it has the letters of vag, and means pebbles, so gravel might work. From this we take G, V and E.

The final clue is

> Ideals. A synonym of principles which includes the letters of sla. From this we take I and E (short form of that is - i.e.).

Finally, we have

> the picture. The letters taken above can be rearranged into "B Negative", which is a 1-8 answer involving blood. I'm guessing the picture might be Hamlet holding a skull (the famous "To be, or not to be" speech is to do with survival, and you could say that he is "B"-ing quite negative in that scene...)

Comment: Brilliant!! Spot on! The last pun wasn't exactly what I had in mind. But,it's ok

Comment: Try to find the final picture pun. It's easy now that you have figured out the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Partial - (Updated)

> It seems the manager is trying to solve a cross-word.

Ok, time to see. Ok, the first one. Hmm, Only 5? Og... No. . Wrong order. Oh, easy, easy. The game. What do we have? Bee and

> So, the first one is ***only 5*** letters word including OgNo and a B. The definition is Game. Making it **Bongo** or may be **Bingo**

5 again. Err... Bob...No. This is Slightly tough. Oh, Yes! So, the other, I get a tea.

> It's again a 5 letter word. If the previous one was across, this can be a down. If **tea** is a def here, we get **Black** to be the five letter word. making it form a sequence like
>
> ```
>  B O N G O
>  L
>  A
>  C
>  K
> ```

Now, 6. What’s this? Vag..No,no,no. Ah, Yes! Pebbles. Oh, Ev Ji. Nice to meet you.

> If Pebbles is a def here. I can only get it to hint towards **Flints**. Plural as it says pebbles and Ev(might sound like F)

Ok, Short that is

> **i.e.**

Comment: I am afraid, No. 1st one is correct though.